# How to make bower install only main file?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I want only the minified and if presented - gzipped version of some library, not the whole bunch of source code!

Comment: Any efforts so far...? You can't expect us to do everything for you.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer

Comment: People add bower_components to the .gitignore file and after `bower install` people extract the relevant files using grunt or gulp or the tool mentioned above. Heres a gulp plugin that does it https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower-files Your webserver should serve gzipped versions of your files automatically if the requesting browser supports it.